# Script to iterate through html file and create csv file

Tags: html, bash, csv, unix, scripting

I have a html file which contains a list of dependencies for a project i'm working on. It has the following format:

-- some html

```
  <p><strong>Module Name:</strong> spring-web</p>
   <p><strong>Module Group:</strong> org.springframework</p>
   <p><strong>Module Version:</strong> 4.2.1.RELEASE</p>
```

-- more html

```
 <p><strong>Module Name:</strong> google-http-client</p>
    <p><strong>Module Group:</strong> com.google.http-client</p>
    <p><strong>Module Version:</strong> 1.19.0</p>
```

etc

i want to create a csv file from this html file
The csv file will have the format for each record:

Module Name, Module Group, Module Version

e.g.
google-http-client,com.google.http-client,1.19.0

Any idea how to do this with a script?

Comment: Use an XML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint, ...).

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try!

```
#!/bin/bash
inFile=$1
outFile=$2

join () {
 local del=$1
 shift
 IFS="$del"
 source <(
        cat <<SOURCE
 echo "\${$1[*]}"
SOURCE
 ) 
 unset IFS
}

declare -a CSV=('"Module Name","Module Group","Module Version"')
declare -a keysAccepted=('Name' 'Group' 'Version')

declare -i nMandatoryKeys=${#keysAccepted[@]}
declare -A KeyFilled
rxKeysAccepted='('$(join '|' keysAccepted)')'
while read line; do
        [[ $line =~ \<strong\>Module\ $rxKeysAccepted:\</strong\>[[:space:]]*([^<]+)\</p\> ]] || continue
        key=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        val=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        KeyFilled[$key]=$val
        if (( ${#KeyFilled[@]} == nMandatoryKeys )); then
                unset csvLine
                for k in ${keysAccepted[@]}; do
                        csvLine+=${csvLine:+,}${KeyFilled[$k]}
                done
                KeyFilled=()
                CSV+=($csvLine)
        fi
done <"$inFile"

(( ${#CSV[@]} > 1 )) || exit 1

join $'\x0a' CSV >"$outFile"
```

Comment: line 2: declare: -A: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]

Comment: This code will work on BASH 4 (4 is a major version number), but this version of BASH is default for all modern *nix'es i know...

Comment: Thanks and how do i pass my file as an argument without having to copy it after 'EOHTML' .

Comment: what if i want to add another column to each line, e.g. license. <h2>License: Apache </h2> .  Where should i add this pattern match?

Comment: Modify: "declare -a CSV"  (Add the header for new column), "declare -a keysAccepted" - add new column name, "[[ $line =~ ..." - replace regular expression: \<strong\>Module\ $rxKeysAccepted:\</strong\>([[:space:]]*([^<]+)\</p\>|<h2>[[:space:]]*([^<]+)[[:space:]]*</h2>) Use ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} instead of ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

Comment: Sorry! "val=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}" instead of "val=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" !

Comment: why <h2>[[:space:]]*([^<]+)[[:‌​space:]]*</h2>  , don't i need an if statement depending on which pattern match is taken

Comment: and shouldn't i use something like |\<h4\>(License:)[[:space:]]*([^<]+)\</h4\>

Comment: It's up to you to parse file line - there are no "bullet proof" to do so, because you always need to adapt your code to your real input. To parse html line you may use grep -Po (aka "pcregrep"), sed -r, BASH internal regexp-matching... My code is engine around the parsing, parsing is too specific to real cases.

Answer (score 1):

If your source file is consistent (all three fields exist together in the same order) you can try this...

```
$ sed -nr 's_\s*<p><strong>Module (Name|Group|Version):</strong> (.*)</p>_\2_p' file\
  | awk 'ORS=NR%3?",":RS'
spring-web,org.springframework,4.2.1.RELEASE
google-http-client,com.google.http-client,1.19.0
```